# Has the research into the apparent "Pause" in GMSTs produced a substantially better explanation?

Tags: climate-change, climate, climate-models

Zeke Hausfather [tweets](https://twitter.com/hausfath/status/1321154927440195584)

> Just six years ago many in the scientific community were obsessing
> over the apparent "pause" or "hiatus" in surface temperatures. It
> famously made it into the 2013 IPCC report in Box 9.2, which featured
> this 15-yr comparison with climate models.

[image]

Clearly a lot of research was performed on the subject of the pause/hiatus (as demonstrated by it featuring in the IPCC report), but my question is what were the significant changes to our understanding of the *apparent* (1) pause/hiatus adding/overturning the explanation given by [Foster and Rahmstorf](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-9326/6/4/044022/meta) in 2011 (largely ENSO, volcanic forcing and solar variation).

Obviously some of the research was on like-for-like comparison of models and observations and biases in the observations, but I am more interested in our understanding of internal climate variability.

(1) "Apparent" as there was no statistically significant evidence for the existence of a change in the underlying rate of warming, and as Hausfather [points out](https://twitter.com/hausfath/status/1321154930640519168), a careful analysis of the last fifteen years worth of data tells the opposite story.

[image]

Comment: I'll take that as a "no" then! ;o)